why can I not fund my regtest named wallet?
I am using Bitcoin Core version v25.99.0-cbf385058bd6

I get the current blockheight
I create a named wallet
I verify that it's in <bitcoin-dir>/regtest/wallets/
I create a new bech32m address
I mine 101 blocks to the address
I get the current blockheight and verify it is 101 blocks later

The balance of my wallet is still zero.
What am I doing wrong?
> bitcoin-cli -regtest getchaintips
[
  {
    "height": 23534,
    "hash": "01884ed85ea0c2142e578237098e74d8d8e8f79398cb84fc5c11a21302a0f779",
    "branchlen": 0,
    "status": "active"
  }
]
> bitcoin-cli -regtest createwallet my-test-wallet
{
  "name": "my-test-wallet"
}
> ls ~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/regtest/wallets/my-test-wallet/
wallet.dat              wallet.dat-journal
> bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=my-test-wallet getbalance
0.00000000
> bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=my-test-wallet getnewaddress "" bech32m
bcrt1p3jderh6kwjtvcy67cwr863xg2n98c8rx8u6a94qyr7qk3ujvxagqm0wjvn
> bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=my-test-wallet generatetoaddress 101 bcrt1p3jderh6kwjtvcy67cwr863xg2n98c8rx8u6a94qyr7qk3ujvxagqm0wjvn
[
  "40cdb3fc05b37d37a0653a710444b51e2ef266a0084c02a34c630a4ac15da07f",
  "34a55c80767b0774ed12e7e60a7df517fb32967a4b76b98539485739a71335e2",
  "77539a3ef7cff0b5b23c708b56d76690b6fb5c84ecb3f7459105ee62b64234b3",
  "43bdcfa08c709b33c302fb9288a791565aae4bf9ab73e6752e43c021d1e1d88c",
  "79075cbdc092fc72c0c755dfb2e76651bcdba5f72298153cd9c1931fdf9ba4ce",
  "64b10a9707a42073ea9bb74bb71ca1c576c20001eb182fb81b9c1dcb57552086",
  "7e3a35cc6480a825db995b7b8fdc363415236c9e08c83dddf5fe73ef5e77128f",
  "5874b187584337b3d2b3bbc6a5fe62e1f11caa7644416ae127e5551ee3505e00",
  "376883cdad3086ebfc1dac970dad78b3be23a725a084f0c165c8f28e43f7d5a8",
  "13b43a751dca0b286545b219e2a0b79bd67ce4708b8b5742c9892f2905691837",
  "31744c76dd4a60a82bee6f7f3622e30c22ce4f8bbeef1e6eada0a4bd4b0029e1",
  "5e59baeb67f4ace0956a89e42a382b0f1093dc48bab6fc05e075327aa8b76a89",
  "19c3bc1457bba90f676ddce2a7044db7edb935d171bafd1ba2c0d3cb74918de9",
  "71bec8c988c3c1175249ec47079dad4c26eff0aad0d41d273db05131593f1963",
  "0fe411004c21b956b90fb782ccde5cba0c2349c02964fb5a2a1678985f846acc",
  "07afb93edaa8ca28c131af6dd9f5ae9c306ef6a98646d8a045ca540e024bfcf3",
  "55867bbdc3652f5167165ea839c54436666c88d8596384c97383aa814e4f3fa4",
  "4837b83d2107ceb8c37f0f2fd650f2caa763194ffcc6d4f24a72e4a7f72c4eda",
  "322352edb7c42391173b470449e8f332ab452f56b5c0a6bec393be98613a510d",
  "49065488e0033054ab96a088730f1118a60331f4543b57c1467fa5e5f29cd472",
  "78c9afbc1b6047da4b4e4053791d02bc04dea5dddf3fa02134f33e390d1ae8e7",
  "654f4b60282ecd94649b3eff36526c3cefbf6e4b68d9275ed55c9bba28d90e5e",
  "4556526c0794293e950076cfba6550b7c701746ba907edbfb58478053fe4189e",
  "34962ac5b25a5000412d0bbd2d8b9b0454459ba7db88a91694755ecb89c43cd9",
  "2dd4466c9aa51ceb6d108095119350009e456b472aabed5418dfdf2c2ba0bef9",
  "36db0bc7d3da3f369d5ea4e04d5c7709765decc20ae8cefc0fccb64aa551b345",
  "1c30b58556d425308f47d960322b8a7abb0bffd451eb075217d7cefe9b689345",
  "6b24d6188960e1637ca4f15ebbfc99a6314afac153e5ef2aed4777bca8238049",
  "5ba939f6a092ba3c87988a20f1d7c798ff94971aa872cc322c9b4379a63e9b22",
  "643fe8b2c10360a679946e99a453e3d9877ff40484be12f11949e43ba9ce8988",
  "4db82357de82d878329116ee5afaaa45756d8431a1ac950a29c24fca2ab651f9",
  "4001cfd14c288aaa0efdd160c557e7c35701cbe0214735f68cee69ee3547c7a3",
  "0fcad6f5513ede892f444e6313f965e24358845fd4f28b42a23304a4bc4aec13",
  "2f9624d5fb294f6c040b9d930fd9f60e0990be8f27c9ffe1a0aafb7a1695c45f",
  "407034f34e1d7ec72e7a510c564f80c69b2ff32a76b77ea895bab21059ff8381",
  "4a36b8e54a9553be0123c77b5bd88381060e72c47207a1a36aa9508835a4a18f",
  "5eb91128a2fbf58793463ad547885d1866a5293652d3c0f48e2857e8c741d5dc",
  "44aeb0788d03212844066a5b803c18827b4310210214af21bf5101a860dc1794",
  "0b80155f207c27894999b8aef6b803daf52df953578f777b2234ae8a779970c9",
  "38638daab0557f0188c74b74b361ad5a8ae8b29c551c225388904acc50ba4744",
  "3a826abca36eb821db64b6488ce5fb383a959fe9757ee2b1dbbac651dc327d33",
  "7e73f4c49a4a391bd8adf0e71fe65ef32c07fb2c4cdea55b1741a54d27cf27ed",
  "7d4884840057eaf986263be82048d5cac85e1af609d390f9f1e05367f58c26ae",
  "552ebf48cf5a9795fdc3f0daa90ec74e50aca5b6f773f052d321a809073504fb",
  "067844068b5bfb3a12fa0eda7eead3f87ba9b77eedaa4758cd6bfaa33597ec37",
  "5a42b649614f019309d43ce254e4bf6d54b290edc48f3a7aadcac93d5e8d3e2c",
  "0c896192cba61b044c6175624ab1a0af21fe5cddd23535affaade40d7a7046fd",
  "4f1b08e2d4286793449e03b18af9848f0301d153aa9f592c8e0c3c0bf9f2b651",
  "166f31cdf4c282981ffa00c0c48a9bc192d94bdb30ac06ddc10f6058ce40d4f5",
  "127c85685d458f71b314db0938ede22131f028a13635c77de6a20ee3f65f3a94",
  "5cc55ec9e3144960d3e96723bd143422447ef09722a40cf2a93ca051ae5ec074",
  "3befaff7cdfabd762884d4ed39b8c44164585d9a83d5c0a732e58b2c2dd59645",
  "102fa5ba4b78ae3ff14a14a215da37787eb442336a05a13aef595d11798a4b86",
  "59c84ca96796a554ce098472977377245b2e896ab58f3a2737c3950fe305e884",
  "6055a4f0c5dfa1fe27c6414679f1868b0a34a213f723e5a98824f0e403be3f0d",
  "64585eabd5612ba77234da1b13de0d03dd8041ea80048965db69aba6f1fdae10",
  "66b23a788c2765d33592d26f6c71d395432e13a4e224d7f11dbdf996aeb877f7",
  "2d8180b05fad1f4bd5e684a914f0111bb824964fd6a2c487f436a400c01cda8d",
  "7556ec7b5861d36b6738eb0f9380dc39d9ef5fe1b8b6c1546cc73d0479a7528a",
  "491cd3a34267de9bb9806995572cad10a5536e4ebe21832dac72439d406031bb",
  "2ba9593e7ac1a77ee5309c08e770de45a7b11299311b5a030a4befb24c115a58",
  "02c451d099c3fd070f463d1798e89fb2b8f058b03169e54eb3d33babd70d8e9d",
  "6f3aeba45060406cfb2e095a692352b44903c201768f628231e6581be32c5797",
  "28008664a67305de9ad58bc90e51651e508e26a38122b9213cbc789d7f2b29fe",
  "3bf8ae82821498a3a114f7edac77f8c5d65d77045abc2b1e0512109455ccc471",
  "69a394736312fcf5a184e2fd9086a6f7004ae85ce28f379f4830bcc8098103c2",
  "4341c0ca65c65e32d04b9a3e85d8ea3a39fb3053cc91c2777e9c2db38427024e",
  "09e01c6f7b165a14a3511bba13b0b36935c5258d6e30b15bf1d1f5dc123529f2",
  "1dc03f6b9d3564062d9d52a458ef02f44fc231a1e5ef8da6728cf625a0a41e7f",
  "2779b983dc39828b708756dd6e680a0e3ef785313a4620fc58310c4cce49947c",
  "1458035817704386f18b6c9c83692eff386a0764578f0a58ff021a34ba11af26",
  "011ad33cb99e7150ae171897815666b06bd73fed285bb40396a1d1da6740af83",
  "650eab9341d6c9bea719f2646872f55369f8b3b092aa81ae9e712530e9b3b74f",
  "31b7283b2b6c6a35b289309e906d4dd5ae1aaaac4b6586bdeb1eaa879ffe1a80",
  "5826883ae1104fe833558f00b4d6b581dca88ef3a7680319b19dfb692d039b6b",
  "18c9ac98d100215e8605ff45be1821e64f05d0b853268e613c409e5bb9d02b6e",
  "490cf26cc49ee657c04a634a4f68eee514899119113fa9182d0dbfef7279c449",
  "48885e981bbbe25a8de1cd7555527351bddf67f381813c97e1f66e2a9fe1e67a",
  "479ad643362dd6e3b7bd7b05081e1563bd771909ef8270846d18d997cfe3ac26",
  "17094452389ea61deb98dc1c68fe4faf7f84d60d6f7f33a7a245e89e717f56e3",
  "4b3dc100043a0e969ebf00d0674f4c9ff0eb58fbccb8535c70512d2138482ffa",
  "0def7686d76348688dd1e451a4202fbbb306a92847eaf1a4fb0aa6bb1e7f5a7d",
  "739fb944aaf3afa7972c296626c511d43c38201d52a9e465eb243cd7bbd22cf0",
  "0e3ba82560cf395678439fa285945fd73b6ac5046d1bc9914fd8a4264a78e2d8",
  "20858133357de8af127657c7d0ec5eaa169b4bde2e7be9e223f6c41f413d40da",
  "18da25620e8e20e90c7849d45f1bf5c4dfb03c8e73f4ecc6f057ce9c79d21c16",
  "0378c0133613c0dbe76dd626c052109ab652575f811f63b4066d0e3c2afa8d0e",
  "23477d585ae84a358edd4d15836cd87093317f5aad885f4771e0987b89b21e88",
  "7ffec7929b63f3797e0b3ed7a34820414281ac07dca54faa97246eb6beed6a4a",
  "0aa44c2faf7ff90c8e8510152ae20b40a5d8aaa3fd796b0cbe6adab69f0dc00f",
  "7ed6d40df0812f7dab90ae4be01b0474aa168e89e304339c7f5cad61e1411558",
  "5943aa6f3532367fb83719c0e837ccab4448a44dd40e8ecd58928505f3c561a9",
  "17df2de0d67c3a28edfa9384ca1bb35a5db3ed617e33f9bc48f2d21ed9b03e7d",
  "492d8ccb60253d7285590317bbc26b7ac6f61d63578d0b31898c31b5864f58a9",
  "0cb7c7491a83487d605bb0fa357beb684bada46b792cafbcb6569daf452b2fd1",
  "42fa54512bf69a3aec904e2e5f8ab49353f21342e573a352160036b8823b8eea",
  "12fe259e90387fe48ae03f1af1c4019681f13fda48c8039c5b22d837463b9fc2",
  "251d665d6bf514bda8c6ad5d523f14d88e1b594f37a6d251aff0f95c6e79ab97",
  "5b9673ab761c13639872ad9a73d5947ec16e313b0409fe736bea83ad0b6ee216",
  "54761fe95456fc5a309964f6d058bc30742a601d2ec69cd65de57a8c93abd288",
  "01884ed85ea0c2142e578237098e74d8d8e8f79398cb84fc5c11a21302a0f779"
]
> bitcoin-cli -regtest getchaintips
[
  {
    "height": 23635,
    "hash": "410460c85ec568516f3b36eb1b97ff324e6160a7b4968bf2f0db035de2881fe0",
    "branchlen": 0,
    "status": "active"
  }
]
> bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcwallet=my-test-wallet getbalance
0.00000000 <-- why???????????????????


The regtest halving interval is 150 blocks. With a block height of 23534, there have been 156 halving intervals. With that many intervals, the block reward is 0.

From what block height did you start mining at? Mining thousands of blocks when the block subsidy is already 0 is not going to change your balance - the block reward will always be 0.

is there a way to change the halving interval?

The halving interval can only be changed by modifying the software, and doing that will also represent a hard fork and further present issues if you have to validate the historical chain. Is there any reason that you have to use that particular regtest chain? If not, I suggest just deleting the entire regtest datadir and starting from scratch.

I just deleted my regtest and started over and it does the exact same thing..

err.. ok maybe not.. i mined 1 block and had a balance 0 zero.. then i did 100 blocks and now i have a balance of 100..  is there a minimum number of blocks I must mine to get a reward (in other words, why did I still have a balance of zero after mining one block)

Regtest still has the coinbase maturity requirement: newly generated coins are only spendable once they have 100 confirmations. The wallet will therefore not show immature coins in getbalance, however you will see them if you use getbalances, although they remain unspendable and the wallet will not try to spend those UTXOs.
